# Library sending SMTP email using implicit SSL for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, email, ssl

System.Net.Mail doesn't support implicit SSL, System.Web.Mail is deprecated. I've tried [Aegis Implicit Mail (AIM)](https://sourceforge.net/p/netimplicitssl/wiki/Home/), but it [doesn't support Unicode](https://sourceforge.net/p/netimplicitssl/tickets/4/). Are there any other free library for sending SMTP email using implicit SSL for .NET?

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it asks for an external resource.

Comment: MailKit helped me

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/

It supports implicit SSL and uncode

Answer (score 4):

Sending email using System.Net.Mail with SSL is as simple as setting the `EnableSsl` flag to `true` and choosing the right port:

```
MailMessage email = new MailMessage()
{
    From = "sender@sender.com",
    Subject = "subject",
    Body = "body"
};
email.To.Add("recipient@recipient.com");
using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
{
    smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtpClient.Port = 587;
    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.Send(email);
}
```

Have a look at [NetImplicitSsl](https://sourceforge.net/p/netimplicitssl/wiki/Home/) for implicit SSL:

```
var emailer = new SmtpSocketClient();
emailer.Host = "your mail server address";
emailer.Port = 465;
emailer.EnableSsl = true;
emailer.User = "mail sever user name";
emailer.Password = "mail sever password" ;
emailer.AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationType.PlainText;
```

Comment: SmtpClient hasn't properties User, Password and AuthenticationMode

Comment: @Tural, sorry that was from a library, please see the update.

Comment: this library doesn't support unicode. https://sourceforge.net/p/netimplicitssl/tickets/4/